# Which meaning of 'incident to' ? - 1932 US

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese, ambiguity

[Source:](http://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/287/45) *Powell v Alabama* (1932)

> It is true that great and inexcusable delay in the enforcement
>   of our criminal law is one of the grave evils of our time.
>   Continuances are frequently granted for unnecessarily long
>   periods of time, and delays **incident to** *the disposition of
>   motions for new trial* and hearings upon appeal have come in
>   many cases to be a distinct reproach to the administration of
>   justice. The prompt disposition of criminal cases is to be
>   commended and encouraged. But, in reaching that result, a
>   defendant, charged with a serious crime, must not be stripped
>   of his right to have sufficient time to advise with counsel and
>   prepare his defense. To do that is not to proceed promptly in
>   the calm spirit of regulated justice, but to go forward with the
>   haste of the mob.
>
> [1.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incident) **(incident to)** Liable to happen because of; resulting from:
>
> 1.1 [Law] Attaching to:

Did Justice Sutherland mean that [1.] the disposition caused  delays afterwards [1.1.] or that delays existed before *the disposition of motions for new trial*? How do you determine/deduce the right meaning ?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: it means delays before the disposition.

Long answer: I would think it would be self-evident that the definition of a term from a legal dictionary would be the definition to go with when deciphering a legal text. Which, by the way, is the only intent of this answer. This answer is not legal advice nor is it intended to be. For legal advice, consult an attorney. Although I'm not advising that either, or advising against it.

I don't know what *incident to* actually means in legalese, but if you look at other uses, such as

[Search incident to arrest](http://definitions.uslegal.com/s/search-incident-to-arrest/) *incident to* apparently means a search done *upon arrest* or *associated with* or *coinciding with*... which if this does not provide a specific definition seems to point in the direction. Thus it is a search *attached to* an arrest.

The author of this text is talking about delays in the legal system. A *continuance* is one type of delay.

A delay *incident to* the disposition of something would seem to mean a delay *coinciding with* or *associated with* or *attached to,* which, by the way, does not seem all that far from *due to,* as in a search *due to* an arrest.

Filing for a motion for a retrial brings with it a certain **delay**, in that an amount of time will necessarily pass between the filing of such a motion and the *disposition* of (judgment on) that motion.

Thus, it appears the delays incident to the disposition of certain motions are talking about delays *attendant upon*, *attached to*, *coinciding with* the time it takes to render a disposition.

Otherwise, why would the next sentence encourage *the prompt disposition of criminal cases*?

Finally  there is nothing I have done that you could not have done: search the Internet for other uses of *incident to*, *disposition,* look at the context, and so forth and use a little common sense, which is probably all that the legal system allows.

Comment: +1 for *self-evident that the definition of a term from a legal dictionary would be the definition to go with when deciphering a legal text*. -1 to OP for not thinking of that in the first place.